# Using an expression on the Label Manager tools

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I am trying to display two labels in each polygon and I want to show One label showing  Year 1 and show another line showing in 140,000 acres. I will use that in the Label Manager and use it in an expression.

I was able to write like this Math.round([Acres]) and it only shows 14000 but does not show the comma like this 14,000.

How do I insert a comma to write in an expression ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within your label manager or label panel in the ArcMap label properties, click the **expression** button.

Ensure the parser (at the bottom) is set to VBScript

In the upper-right hand corner of the expression box (that holds the expression itself), check the **advanced** box

You'll now have an expression that looks like this:

```
Function FindLabel ( [fieldName] )
  FindLabel = [fieldName]
End Function
```

Now simply add the FormatNumber option to your expression, wrapping your field name in parentheses:

```
Function FindLabel ( [fieldName] )
  FindLabel = FormatNumber([fieldName])
End Function
```

Now click the **verify** button to see how your number will look:

```
20,111,001.00
```

For more information, see this Microsoft article on the FormatNumber function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfta99yt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: good stuff @PROBERT!!!

Comment: Exactly a lot of goodies stuff out there @mapBaker

Comment: @PROBERT don't forget to mark it as your answer if it works for ya... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the Fields tab of the layer properties page, select your field, click in the Number Format section, click the ... ellipsis, and check Show thousands separators.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or the python equivalent for quick and simple , separator formatting would be something along the lines of

```
"{:,}".format(14000)
```

Obviously replacing the value with field name or rounding function and field name.

```
"{:,}".format(round([fieldname]))
```

Other potentially helpful python answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators

Python documentation for formatting https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language